# cannot access zzbfm mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL); class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm not found

Tags: java, android, class, gradle

I am making GPS Tracker system and I tried to add google maps tracking but I am having this error when I try to run app by emulator:

error: cannot access zzbfm
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm not found

I believe its because of different versions of dependencies but I dont know which versions I should use. I tried many versions but still no solution.

and here is my module build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

here is my project bundle.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{

          url "https://maven.google.com"

    }
    maven{


        url "https://maven.fabric.io/public"

    }
}
```

what should I do?

Comment: Does the emulator have Google Play services installed?

Comment: Yes. emulator have google play services.